# License change of original source from Apache 2.0 to LGPL

Tags: licensing, lgpl, apache, change

About a year or so ago, I forked a project licensed under Apache 2.0 and made extensive changes and additions to the code, a good portion of which I contributed back freely to the community.

Recently, the code moderator changed the licensing to LGPLv3, and I wanted to find out if I was correct in my belief that this licensing change does not apply to the code I checked out more than a year ago, specifically not forcing me to comply to LGPL and leaving me free to do as I wish under Apache 2.0 as long as I do not "taint" my fork with new code from the original project that was written under the new licensing scheme.

Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 9):

The code moderator cannot retroactively force a new license on you for the original code that was written under the original license.